# Cached version of JSON file when importing into typescript

Tags: angular

In my SPA I am importing a JSON file like this

```
import jsonconfig from './environment/conf.json'
```

I setup json typings (json-typings.d.ts)

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
 }
```

Everything working fine locally. Reading values from JSON

But the problem arised when I deployed the App. I am using CI pipeline to build and octopus for deployment. Once built the project, using Octopus I altered the JSON file for different environments.

Here is how my JSON looks like

```
{
ClientID:xxxxx
RedirectUri:http://xxxx
key:xxxx
}
```

I am alterying the JSON file after built is because for different environments,the above parameters will be different.

But the problem is even after changing the values in the deployed files, it looks like it still uses old value before we changed it.

I went to azure portal to check what is the value in JSON file and it looks like its updated without any issue.

So above JSON looks like this now

```
{
ClientID:yyyyyy
RedirectUri:http://yyyy
key:yyyyyyyeeee
}
```

But application when execute still shows old values. FOr example before building the redirecturi was http://localhost:4200. In my code redirect URI is updated to live url. But application still redirect to localhost. It feels like its not taking the data from live updated JSON file.

How to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0):

I've fix my issue with this method.
I add file json in assets.

**assets/environment/conf.json**

```
{
ClientID:xxxxx
RedirectUri:http://xxxx
key:xxxx
}
```

when page load it will call service to call json file

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ConfigService } from './services/config.service';
providers: [
   {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (appConfigService: ConfigService) => {
          return () => {                    
              return appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
          };
      },
  }
]
```

**config.service.ts**

```
export interface Config {
    ClientID: string;
    RedirectUri: string;
    key: string;
  }

loadAppConfig() {
        this.http
            .get<Config>("assets/environment/conf.json")
            .pipe(
                retry(2), 
            )
            .subscribe(
                (data: Config) => {
                    this.appConfig = { ...data };
                },
                (error) => {
                     console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
```